# column field cumulative sum update with constant value from input

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update

```
UPDATE Payment payment SET payment.amount =(payment.amount + :amount) WHERE payment.id =:personId
```

Want cumulative sum updated in same column field. That is, "payment" field in Payment Table should be updated with added value of "amount+payment" in the same field. But the above query creating value of "payment" every time in new row with the "amount" value.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you saying that it is inserting a new row, not updating? That doesn't sound right at all. I'm guessing somewhere in your code you have somewhere where it is also inserting a record but an `UPDATE` does not `INSERT` records.

Comment: `payment.id =:personId` looks a bit fishy. Shouldn't it be something along the lines of `payment.person_id =:personId`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  UPDATE Payment payment, (select @amount:=:amount) as a 
  SET payment.amount =(@amount:=@amount + payment.amount)
  WHERE payment.id =:personId;
```